# Вывод тегов с данными из массива используя jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Хочу вывести на экран список в котором будут вставлены данные из массива полученные с серверной части.

```
function showRoot() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'app/main.php',
    type: 'get',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            let result = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                if (key === 0) {
                    $('#tree').append($("<ul style='list-style-type: none;'><li id='"+ value['id'] +"' " +
                        "parent_id='"+ value['parent_id'] +"'><p class='mb-0 pl-3'>" + value['text'] + "</p>" +
                        "<button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button><button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button<li></ul>"));
                }
            });
            $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                if (i > 0){
                    let r = item.id - 1;
                    $("#"+r).append($("<ul style='list-style-type: none;'><li id='"+ item['id'] +"' " +
                        "parent_id='"+ item['parent_id'] +"'><p class='mb-0 pl-3'>" + item['text'] + "</p>" +
                        "<button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button><button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button<li></ul>"));
                }
            });
        } else return "";
    }
});
}
```

То есть если в БД имеются какие либо данные то их нужно вывести на экран при этом 0 элемент нужно вставить в блок `div` с `id='tree'`, а последующие данные в последний тег `li`

Вот как выглядит index.php

```
<body class="my-2 mx-3">
<button id="create-root" class="btn btn-success">Create root</button>
<div id="tree"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js?35123123"></script>
</body>
```

js файл где вызывается метод showRoot

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#create-root").click(function () {
    createRoot($(this).siblings('li').attr('id'));
});
showRoot();
$('#tree').on('click', '.add', function () {
    createNode($(this).siblings('li').attr('id'));
});
$('#tree').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    deleteRoot($(this).siblings('li').attr('id'));
});
});
```

Результат должен быть такой:

```
<body class="my-2 mx-3">
<button id="create-root" class="btn btn-success">Create root</button>
<div id="tree">
<ul style='list-style-type: none;'>
    <li id='1' parent_id='0'>
        <p class='mb-0 pl-3'> Root </p>
        <button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button> 
        <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button>
            <ul style='list-style-type: none;'>
            <li id='2' parent_id='1'>
                <p class='mb-0 pl-3'> Root </p>
                <button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button>
                <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button >
            </li>
            </ul>
            <ul style='list-style-type: none;'>
            <li id='3' parent_id='1'>
                <p class='mb-0 pl-3'> Root </p>
                <button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button>
                <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button >
                <ul style='list-style-type: none;'>
                <li id='4' parent_id='3'>
                    <p class='mb-0 pl-3'> Root </p>
                    <button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button>
                    <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button >
               </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js?35123123"></script>
</body>
```

Не могу понять что сделано не верно так как выводится только 0 элемент массива.

Comment: А в какой виде сервер отдает ответ, как это выглядит? Выведите в косность `result`

Comment: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 292, parent_id: 0, text: "Root"}
1: {id: 293, parent_id: 0, text: "Root"}
2: {id: 294, parent_id: 0, text: "Root"}
3: {id: 295, parent_id: 0, text: "Root"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: в виде массива в который вложен ассоциативный массив

Comment: Выведите в консоль в начале цикла $.each `console.log(key, value)` и посмотрите что он выдает

Comment: 0 {id: 292, parent_id: 0, text: "Root"}
id: 292
parent_id: 0
text: "Root"
__proto__: Object
1 {id: 293, parent_id: 0, text: "Root"}
id: 293
parent_id: 0
text: "Root"
__proto__: Object
2 {id: 294, parent_id: 0, text: "Root"}
id: 294
parent_id: 0
text: "Root"
__proto__: Object

Comment: `$("#"+r)` такого элемента в DOM не существует. Или уже существует?

Comment: `$("#r")` такой вариант будет верный?

Comment: Я скопировал ваше решение https://codepen.io/Nekiy2/pen/poyLJPP?editors=1010 что не так работает? Игорь ниже так же сделал только через сниппет.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно работающий код получился следующим

```
$.each(result, function (key, value) {
if (value.parent_id === 0) {
$('#tree').append($("<ul style='list-style-type: none;'><li id='"+ value['id'] +"' " +
"parent_id='"+ value['parent_id'] +"'><p class='mb-0 pl-3'>" + value['text'] + "</p>" +
"<button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button> <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button><li></ul>"));
}
});
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
if (item.parent_id > 0){
$('#' + item.parent_id).append($("<ul style='list-style-type: none;'><li id='"+ item['id'] +"' " +
"parent_id='"+ item['parent_id'] +"'><p class='mb-0 pl-3'>" + item['text'] + "</p>" +
"<button class='delete btn btn-danger'>-</button> <button class='add btn btn-success'>+</button><li></ul>"));
}
});
```